# Adding User :name to devise invitable edit.html.erb form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add the :name input field into the edit.html.erb form that the users are directed to after accepting the devise invitation.

However, the after filling out the form the :name input field is blank (not storing in database).

Does this happen because rails 4 uses strong parameters?

I've been trying to sort this out for a while and can't seem to get anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

There's a wiki page written up about this on [devise_invitable's github repo](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/How-To:-Allow-updating-additional-attributes-when-accepting-invitation)

In that article, they

1. subclass `Devise::InvitationsController`
2. override `update`
3. put a `before_action` to change the sanitized parameters for `:accept_invitation`

However, I wonder if it wouldn't be possible (and much simpler) to just put the following in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #...
  before_action :devise_configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  #...
  protected
  def devise_configure_permitted_parameters
    # Devise 3 (deprecated in Devise 4.0 and removed in Devise 4.2)
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) << :name
    # Devise 4
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:name])
  end
```

I've done that for devise's `:sign_up` and `:account_update` actions and it worked without overriding their controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for the above problem.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:accept_invitation) do |u|
  u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :invitation_token)
end
```

In my case, I permitted `first_name` and `last_name`. Most importantly, permit `invitation_token` as well otherwise the application will raise an error `missing token`.

FYI, Tested in rails (4.2), devise (3.4.1) and devise_invitable (1.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you need to permit your customized attribute first, in your case :name. It's clearly mentioned in [devise git hub repo](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Rails 4 and 5. I encountered a similar issue on both versions of RoR, and this was how I solved it.

Extend the invitation controller and add the following lines of code to it:

```
#controllers/invitations_controllers.rb
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
def edit
   super
end

private
# add :name to strong params
def update_resource_params
   params.require(:devise_model).permit(:email, :password,:password_confirmation, :name, :invitation_token)
end
```

To extend the default route, you'll need to do the following:

```
#app/routes.rb
devise_for :devise_models, :controllers => { invitations: 'invitations' }
```

:devise_model refer to the model associated with devise, while :devise_models refer to the route associated with devise.